# Apple watch simulator starts watch app with notification view. How to auto start in main?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I didn't have have this problem before! I don't know what I've done. Created an apple watch extension to my project, and connected a few labels to the main storyboard (the main interface controller) and didn't touch the storyboard stuff for the notification and glance scenes (I've checked to add those when adding the extension)

At first, when running the simulator it would enter to the main scene. But now there's a blank notification thing that comes up with "dismiss" and another button above it. Hitting that button allows the regular scene to load.

Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select your watch app as the build target, I guess you've selected your notification scene target right now.

Just select it in the top left corner of Xcode:

[image: target selection tutorial]

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the initial interface has been set to the notification? Here's how to check:

1. Pull down the Project menu, select Scheme, then make sure your WatchKit app is selected.
2. Under the Project menu (again), select Scheme, then Edit Scheme.
3. Select Run in the left panel, then verify that "Watch Interface" is set to "Main" (and not something like "Static Notification")

[image]